# Changing a control's style based on validation (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a very simple form with the following troubled snippet:

```
<asp:Panel class="normal" ID="Panel1" runat="server">
 <strong><asp:Label ID="Panel1Error" class="error" Visible="false" runat="server"/></strong>

 <label for="TextBox1"><em>*</em> Don't leave this blank</label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />

 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="TextBox1RFV" runat="server"
  ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="This field cannot be blank."
  Display="None" />

    <--- other validators --->
</asp:Panel>
```

There are two things I want to do when the page fails validation:

1. Change the style of Panel1 (to one which shows different colors to indicate an error). I was able to do this by calling Page.Validate in Page_Load, then iterating over Page.Validators, getting each validator's parent control, casting it to a Panel, then setting .CssClass Doesn't seem like a superb solution, but it got the job done - is there a better way?
2. I want to take whatever validation error(s) are thrown and put them in the Panel1Error label, as well as set it to visible. This is where I am a bit baffled. I thought at first I could possibly specify the Label in which a validator writes its ErrorMessage, but I had no such luck. If I just toss the validator inside the Label, its formatting messes up the entire layout of the page, regardless of whether I directly assign it the 'error' CSS class or just leave it in the Label.

Just to clarify, in production, I would be doing this process for multiple Panels on a page, each with one form element, preventing me from calling the Panels explicitly and just saying Panel1.CssClass, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would recommend a javascript solution. ASP.NET injects a global js variable called Page_Validators, which is an array of all of the validator spans on the page. I wrote about this on [my blog](http://john.rummell.info/john/blog/post/Apply-the-same-CSS-class-to-all-validators-in-a-web-project.aspx). It's a different solution, but it should give you enough insight to get started.
2. Use [ValidationSummary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.aspx) controls with a [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) for each panel.

Comment: @ #2, trying to clarify again: there are multiple panels, each containing a form element, each with its own validators. From what I understand, ValidationSummary sums up ALL validation on an entire page - what I want is a panel-by-panel (or aesthetically speaking, section-by-section) reporting of errors. If you don't put your name in for example, I want to show the error on the top of the page (in a ValidationSummary), as well as right above the actual form element within a Label, specific to that element.

Answer (score 0):

1. Seems fine if it worked.
2. Use a [ValidationSummary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.aspx) control. Or you can inherit from the controls and override the render event.

Comment: For #2, I'm actually already using a ValidationSummary on the top of the page to collect all the errors from every Panel. I had not thought of overriding the render event, I'll look into that to see how it's done and see if it works.